# How to get the Query values?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, devexpress

```
SqlDatasource1 :   

Table1
-----------
Result_1
-----------
Result_2
```

I have a query, and I want to get a  **Result_2 value** from the query in code behind, in the BeforePrint event, and I don´t want to put a label in the report, how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You forgot the most important part of your post, the part where you explain what you want. As posted there is nothing here. This might be a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I want to get the value from a column in **Table1**, which the datasource is **Sqldatasource1**, In the code behind

Comment: Look at what you posted and ask yourself if you think you would be able to help somebody with only the knowledge of what you posted. You seem to need help here but you haven't provided anywhere near enough information for anybody to be able to help. It looks like the guess posted by Michael McMullin might be close to what you want??

Comment: @SeanLange : I think that I try to explain the best as I can, and I only ask for help, the answer for Michael McMullin does´nt work with my code, and I still trying to find a solution, but anyway thank you for your opinion, for the next time I will try to explain better my questions, thanks.

Comment: Don't wait until next time. Fix your question and you will get an answer. The main reason you aren't getting an answer is not because nobody knows how to do it. It is because you failed to ask a complete question. See if this helps explain the challenge we have on our end. http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually run the Select command on your data source, you could try something like (C#):

```
var dv = new DataView()

dv = Sqldatasource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguements.Empty) as DataView;

if (dv.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRowView rv in dv)
    {
        string Result2Val = rv["Result_2"].ToString();
        // do something with the result...
    }
}
```

I'm sure VB will follow a similar pattern.

Alternatively, try and capture the OnSelected event, if it's already being triggered by another control.